# Math.NET c# Storing complex numbers

Tags: c#, matlab

I have a Matrix

```
inputMatrix = new DenseMatrix(4);

inputMatrix[0, 0] = 0;
inputMatrix[0, 1] = -2;
inputMatrix[0, 2] = 0;
inputMatrix[0, 3] = 0;
inputMatrix[1, 0] = 5;
inputMatrix[1, 1] = 6;
inputMatrix[1, 2] = 0;
inputMatrix[1, 3] = -8;

inputMatrix[2, 0] = 0;
inputMatrix[2, 1] = 0;
inputMatrix[2, 2] = 0;
inputMatrix[2, 3] = -12;

inputMatrix[3, 0] = 0;
inputMatrix[3, 1] = 0;
inputMatrix[3, 2] = 15;
inputMatrix[3, 3] = -16;
```

Math.NET don't have MATLAB `expm()`. So I calculated as explained in MATLAB "help expm" using `[V,D] = eig(inputMatrix)`

When calculate, since input matrix has negative value, I get a result as complex numbers. I want to store these complex numbers in a `Matrix<>`. How can I?

Comment: The problem is not with the Complex data structure. But with the Math.NET matrix. It says it will only accept a double array. But I have complex number array

Comment: I am still looking for a solution. Can anyone help to to implement the MATLAB expm() using Math.Numerics.NET?